# How to iterate though a FirebaseObjectObservable property as an array in Angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I want to be able to do run an `*ngFor` on the `users` property of the `groups` object in my Firebase database.

So far, I'm trying this:

```
<h5>{{ (group$ | async)?.name }}</h5>
<div class="gd-users-container">
  <span *ngFor="let user of (group$ | async)?.users">{{ user.email }}</span>
</div>
```

Where `group$ = getGroup(): FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;`

And the data's structure looks like this:

```
"groups": {
  "marketing": {
    "apps": {
      "someid": {
        "id": "someid",
        "name": "Payroll"
      }
    },
   "id": "marketing",
   "name": "Marketing",
   "users": {
     "23948n": {
       "id": "23948n",
       "email": "someemail@domain.com"
      },
     "asdfasdfasdf": {
       "id": "asdfasdfasdf",
       "email": "someemail@domain.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try the markup above, I get the name of the group back, but I get an error when it comes to the `*ngFor`:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

It makes sense to me why I am receiving that error, because the property `users` on the `group` object is not an array, but rather an object. My question is how to get it so that the `users` property *can* be treated as an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the async pipe in this context. As the error states, `*ngFor` can only bind to iterables, but what the [async pipe does is](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe):

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and *returns the latest value it has emitted*

So you don't get an iterable. Instead, use:

```
*ngFor="let email of emails"
```

EDIT: No, it won't convert it an array. As above, it takes an iterable, so you need to do that yourself, with, say:

```
let emails: [];
Object.keys(group$?.users).map(key => emails.push(group$?.users[key].email)))
```

Add additional properties, or the whole user object, to the array, as you wish. For exaxmple, in ES7's [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```
let users = Object.values(group$.users)
```

And the original `<div *ngFor = "let user of users">{{user?.email}}</div>`

Comment: Okay, so that gets rid of the error, but it still doesn't convert that property to an array to iterate through its objects. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @JoshuaKemmerer See edit: Angular won't mangle your data structure, you need to modify it for yourself.

Comment: @JoshuaKemmerer I appreciate you accepting my answer, but do feel free to post a new answer with the content of your edit. It's perfectly acceptable. I'll leave the edit pending until you do, then reject it (it belongs in a new answer). :)

Comment: Thanks, that looks better to me!

Answer (score 0):

**Response from Joshua:**

So, what I ended up doing was subscribing to the `group` object and created a separate `users$` model that was assigned to `group.users`:

```
this.group$ = this.route.paramMap
  .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
    this.gs.getObjectObservable(params.get('id')));

this.group$.subscribe(snapshot => {
  this.users$ = Object.values(snapshot.users);
});
```

Then I just displayed the data as:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users$">
  {{ user.email }}
</div>
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it seems the easiest. Also, from what I understand of subscriptions and "snapshots", this should work out fine.